# Lists in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the problem is that I have a list which is made of pairs of numbers [ (0,0),(0,1)(0,2) ...etc  and I would like to know how to delete from this list all pairs with the same numbers . List was created by this function.

```
 l1 = []
 def fun2(x,y):
    for x in range(x+1):
        for y in range(y+1):
            l1.append((x,y))
    return l1
```

Comment: write your expected output

Comment: This one doesn't generate duplicates

Comment: @user1767754: I don't thik it's about duplicate pairs. It's about pairs with duplicate numbers. E.g. `(0, 0)`.

Comment: As mentioned below, it's much better to avoid appending the unwanted pairs while building the list in the first place.

Comment: They taught you loops before they taught you ifs?

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid duplicate tuple elements while generating the list. Just add an `if`:

```
def fun2(x, y):
    result = []
    for a in range(x+1):
        for b in range(y+1):
            if a != b:
                result.append((a,b))
    return result
```

This could also be written more succinctly as a list comprehension:

```
result = [(a, b) for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) if a != b]
```

Yet another option is to use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

result = [(a, b) for a, b in product(range(x+1), range(y+1)) if a != b]
```

---

Removing items afterwards is also possible with a list comprehension:

```
result = [pair for pair in result if pair[0] != pair[1]]
```

which creates a new list without the duplicate items then rebinds it to `result`. You can overwrite the list *in place* with:

```
result[:] = [pair for pair in result if pair[0] != pair[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Using [list comprehnsion](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):**

```
lst = [c for c in l1 if c[0] != c[1]]
```

**Method 2: Building the list manually:**

```
lst = []
for elem in l1:
    if elem[0] != elem[1]:
        lst.append(elem)
```